# Using JSF2 @ManagedProperty in Spring managed backing bean

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I have a JSF backing bean that is Spring managed but I would like to be able to make use of the @ManagedProperty from JSF. The following does not work:

```
@Component
@Scope(Scopes.REQUEST)
public class MyRequestBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.bcIndex}")
    private int bcIndex;

    public int getBcIndex() {
        return bcIndex;
    }

    public void setBcIndex(int bcIndex) {
        this.bcIndex = bcIndex;
    }
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I think it's enough using JSF's `@RequestScoped` annotation. Spring context returns a bean instance per HTTP request, JSF does the same, why to mix both concepts?

Comment: [Doesn't look like it's possible with vanilla spring/jsf](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?41321-JSF-injecting-JSF-managed-into-SPRING-managed-bean)

Comment: @kolossus The link you provide looks a bit old-fashioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is quite simple. I know of three ways to do your injection:

1. Use Spring's `@Value` annotation together with implicit El `#{param}` object:

   ```
   @Value("#{param.bcIndex}")
   private int bcIndex;
   ```
2. Make use of `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap` in a `@PostConstruct` / `preRenderView` listener:

   ```
   //@PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       bcIndex = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("bcIndex");
   }
   ```
3. Make a binding in your view utilizing `<f:viewParam>`:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="index" value="#{myRequestBean.bcIndex}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ```